# Restoring full SQL Server backup to a different server is only trying to restore from Log

Tags: sql-server

We are taking a full backup of a SQL Server 2012 database and attempting to restore it to another SQL Server. However when doing this, it only attempts to restore from the log (`.trn`) and not including the full backup (`.bak`).

Here we are selecting both files.

[image: device backups]

After this it is only attempting to restore the TRN file, which of course fails to restore.

[image: only TRN selected]

Is there a proper way to get this to restore both the full and the transaction log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to restore the database backup first with NO RECOVERY.

After that, open the Restore Database window again and select the log backup set(s) you want to apply. This should give you the ability to apply the log backups either completely or to a point in time.